# How to make a simple auto playing slide show with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I want to make a simple slide show that automatically plays when the page is loaded. Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
      <img src="slide_1.png">
   </div>   
   <div>
      <img src="slide_2.png">
   </div>
   <div>
       <img src="slide_3.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow {  

    position: relative; 

    width: 900px; 

    height: 450px;  

}

#slideshow > div { 

    position: absolute; 

}
```

If possible, can someone please provide me with a JavaScript code that will automatically play the slide show, as well as change the slides by using a slide transition, and also have it replay infinite amount of times while the user is still of the page? Also, maybe a navigation that has numbers in the bottom right corner. Here is an example of what I am looking for: (http://www.http://www.suprafootwear.com/). The large slideshow up top is what I want, the only difference is that I want the transition to be a linear slide motion instead of the fade transition. Please maintain the 900px x 450px size. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://www.slidesjs.com/ might be useful.

Comment: Thanks but I need a code that is different than that and customized to my needs. The problem is that I am a noob at JavaScript. Lol

Comment: If you want infinite repeat on load with no buttons to control it, no need for JavaScript. Use CSS keyframe animation or transition. see here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/
http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/

Comment: I suggest http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/

Comment: I update the answer with this example: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple javascript code to make image slider.

```js
(function() {
  var imgLen = document.getElementById('imgGallary');
  var images = imgLen.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var counter = 1;

  if (counter <= images.length) {
    setInterval(function() {
      images[0].src = images[counter].src;
      console.log(images[counter].src);
      counter++;

      if (counter === images.length) {
        counter = 1;
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
})();
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgGallary" class="container">
  <img src="http://www.examiningcalvinism.com/kingdavid.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="300" />
  <img src="http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1611-Bible/1611-King-James-Bible-Introduction.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="300" />
  <img src="http://biblestudyoutlines.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/the-triump-of-david-over-king-hadadezer-of-zobah-1024x729.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="300" />
  <img src="http://www.cgu.edu/Images/news/Flame%20Winter12/KJV-BibleBW.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="300" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
>
> setInterval(function() {    $('#slideshow > div:first')
>       .fadeOut(1000)
>       .next()
>       .fadeIn(1000)
>       .end()
>       .appendTo('#slideshow'); },  3000);