# CSS3 and html Issue with slider

Tags: html, css

Hey i want to add this slider to my site, but it dont have options to move automatically, is there possibillity to add this option using only css commands? for e.g animation: ? if yes pls tell me how.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

html, body { background: #333 url("http://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png"); }

.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

   opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: -5px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-dots">
    <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
    <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
    <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
    <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
    <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by move?

Comment: By moving i mean it will slide from one image to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several links to create your own Automatic Slider/Slideshow. I would suggest reading through the top one:

CSS only:
http://themarklee.com/2013/10/16/simple-crossfading-slideshow-css/

Using JS or JQuery too:
http://demosthenes.info/blog/838/CSSslidy-An-Auto-Generated-Responsive-CSS3-Image-Slider

[How to make a simple auto playing slide show with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222360/how-to-make-a-simple-auto-playing-slide-show-with-javascript)

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-slick-auto-playing-featured-content-slider/

Hope this helps!