# Are there any differences between javascript and jquery for automatic slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm now studying step by step,lastly i tried to make an automatic slideshow and manual click function but my knowledge isn't enough to code that.If i asked people how to do that do this i would have differences answer and style in coding,so i think i have to make it by myself.

1. Are there any differences between javascript and jquery for automatic slideshow?
2. Are there any advantage between javascript and jquery for animation ? (in my case automatic slideshow and manual click)

thank you.(I'm sorry for my english)

Comment: jQuery is a library of functions written in javascript, therefore jquery is javascript. jQuery simplifies a lot of animation type stuff. Some jQuery methods are significantly slower than javascript equivalents - but you're not going to notice that with something as simple as a slideshow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is:
JavaScript is a programmation language created by Brendan Eich in 1995, and jQuery is an Open-Source Javascript Library created by John Resig in 2006.

So Basically there is no big difference, and for the advantage, JQuery doesn't need a lot of knowledges to understand. So if you don't want to break your brain for this automatic slideshow go with Jquery, there is the link : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

And if you want to make it with Javascript there is the link: [How to make a simple auto playing slide show with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222360/how-to-make-a-simple-auto-playing-slide-show-with-javascript)

EDIT: In the two cases, you have a lot of documentations about creating a auto-playing slideshow in js and jquery.

I hope I helped you.

Greetings,

Squarety.

Comment: At this modern and technologics time and for the beginning between javascript and jquery about animation which one should i start first ?